# How to detect a link click with custom attributes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some links like this:

```
<a href="#" track="yes">My Link</a>
```

How can I detect when a link with the **track** attribute is clicked ?

Thanks!

Comment: Making up new attributes usually isn't a good idea. Why don't you use a class instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("a[track]").click(function()
{
    ...
});
```

This will bind a click event to every link with a `track` attribute.

An even better solution is to use live to limit the number of event handler:

```
$("a[track]").live("click", function()
{
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the attribute selector:

```
$("a[track]").click(function(e){
  // Your code
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/uXwSF/

As andre points out in the comments, if you want to get only links where `track='yes'` then do:

```
$("a[track='yes']").click(function(e){
  // Your code
});
```

If you want to get all links with the `track` attribute, but know what the value is then:

```
$("a[track]").click(function(e){
  var shouldTrack = $(this).attr('track');
});
```

Comment: You should use `$("a[track='yes']").click(function() { // ... });` if you only want items where track="yes".

Comment: How about if I have another link with track attribute but they have a different class, as one is to DELETE the other one is to EDIT?